# Windows XP only has 10 Network SMB-Connections; How to count them?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, server-message-block

I read that somewhere but i dont know to which edition it belongs and how it works.

Is this the meaning that if i open the eleventh Word-document from a Fileserver i get an error-message?

How can i count the used network smb-connections?

Additional question: What about Win-7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This restriction is not for outgoing connections, but for incoming connections. If you have a non-server version of Windows, you cannot have more than 10 clients concurrently connecting to a file or print share on that machine.

Comment: To clarify, the 10 concurrent connection\session limit is for file and print services and has no bearing on web, ftp, etc. services that you may be providing from the Windows XP machine.

Comment: IIS does implement the 10 connection limit.  If you're using that to host http, ftp, etc. services on an XP host then you can still run into the limit.

3rd party servers (Apache, etc.) do not have these limitations.

Comment: @afrazier: Are you referring to the 10 inbound SMB connections limit or the 10 concurrent TCP connections per second limit? My understanding is that the 10 inbound SMB connections limit refers to the number of redirector-based connections and is enforced for any file, print, named pipe, or mail slot session, but not for TCP connections such as HTTP, FTP, etc.

Comment: The 10 inbound connections limit.  It's not limited to SMB -- IIS also enforces that restriction on non-server OSes.  3rd party network services aren't limited in such a fashion though.  This has nothing to do with Event ID 4226.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.

You are sure that there is no outbound-limit in networkstack or SMB-protocoll-handler?

Comment: I currently have connections to 4 network printers, 5 mapped drives and 6 UNC paths. This is all SMB connections and totals 15. There's def no outbound limit.